# Lubuntu 14.04 internet connection very slow (ethernet)

Tags: networking, internet

my internet connection is very slow. I have also windows XP installed and it does not have any problem.

The PC is an HP Pavilion t3320.it the ethernet adaptor is "rtl8100"

Comment: Quantify, please.

Comment: So slow that it could not be used... it's 3 hours and it is still downloading an update for firefox... about 5kbps

Comment: Could be a mirror issue. You should try an online speed test.

Comment: It does not eaven load the page for the test

Comment: do you have the same problem connecting to another network's ethernet?

Comment: I can test only one network, and is the network I am writing from. Furthermore the same pc connected to the same network but running XP is able to surf the net without problems

Comment: I think it is a driver problem but I do not know how to solve it

Comment: `lspci -vv | grep -i Ethernet -A 10`

Comment: "grep: 10: file or directory does not exist"

Comment: did you forget the `-A`?

Comment: Sorry I am stupid...https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw3qat4dszbcyhr/IMG_20140907_140037.jpg?dl=0

Comment: now what makes you think this is an 8100 and not an 8139? we can eliminate that question with `lspci -nn | grep -i Ethernet`. other question: what kernel do you have (`uname -r`)? shot in the dark: if you boot with `acpi=off`, `acpi=ht`, `processor.max_cstate=1`, `idle=poll`, or `nolapic_timer`, does it improve anything? you can look at `ifconfig eth0 | grep dropped` to measure if there's any improvement. furthermore you might want to provide `dmesg | grep 8139too`. these ultimately may be useful to add to your question.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers, I am glad to see how linux community is so... cozy?(Google translate).
Well! This is the output of the console: https://www.dropbox.com/s/83lhfii6c7nfmsc/IMG_20140908_185115.jpg?dl=0
Sorry but I am very n00b with linux... how can I boot with the parameters suggested by you?

Comment: I managed to edit the boot parameter and... It works!!!
I do not know which parameter is the right one, I set acpi=off, processor.max_cstate=1, idle=poll
Next I will do some tests and see which one is the right one! (in case anyone had the same problem)
Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux kernel bug tracker has a [bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13830) against this driver that relates to your issue. There are workarounds mentioned in the bug.

I would suggest that you get yourself an account on their Bugzilla and subscribe yourself to the bug. Make sure to point out that it's still relevant in 3.13, since the last comment suggests it was relevant in 3.2. This leads people to think it's not very relevant any more and they pass over it when looking for bugs to fix. It would be good if you could test all of the boot options and see which works best.

tl;dr this is a known issue. Boot with one of the following to get around the problem:

- `acpi=off`
- `acpi=ht`
- `processor.max_cstate=1`
- `idle=poll`
- `nolapic_timer`

You can permanently add one or more of these to your boot by following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation).